# cant use Extensibility lib in my project

Tags: c#, vs-extensibility

I cant use Extensibility lib in my project.

Error:

```
The type or namespace name 'Extensibility' could not be found
```

Using Visual Studio 2010, Framework 4

Comment: I'm trying to do this tutorial  //   public void OnConnection(object application, 
Extensibility.ext_ConnectMode 
connectMode, object addInInst, ref System.Array custom)  // http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa289518(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: on msdn site its said that  Extensibility is a part of System.Object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are talking about this namespace: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/extensibility%28v=VS.100%29.aspx

To use it, add a reference to the **Extensibility** assembly to your project. This assembly should exist in your GAC.

In the future, if you don't know which assembly to use, lookup the concrete type on the MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/extensibility.ext_connectmode.aspx. At the top of the page, it tells you in which assembly the type resides.

Answer (score 0):

Have you added a reference to Extensibility to your project? Without that it won't find the library.

Comment: What is the name of this reference?

Comment: Using Visual Studio's 'Add Reference' dialog, I believe the one you want is called 'Extensibility', assuming you're after the Visual Studio extensibility library (that's what shows up on my installation anyway). If you're actually using some other library that's also called Extensibility, you'll have to check up on what the relevant assembly you need to reference is yourself.